# How to deal with outdated sub-dependencies with NPM?

Tags: npm

I've got a NPM project which have some dependencies declared within its package.json.

In the meantime this project has grown quite old so I wondering how to update the packages to a newer version. But after installing the packages in the latest version, the output of the `npm audit` will still show a lot of critical entries. I've found out that the critical part are not the packages mentioned within my package.json but sub-dependencies. For example by installing package X, my project will inevitably also take risks, since package X itself is dependent on the outdated package Y.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Is there a solution to this?